# Query logic check: to calculate no. of primary keys in db

Tags: sql, sql-server

Results of 1,2 and 3 below are same. Just need to know whether this logic is correct that both of the queries return the value of no. of primary keys..

1.

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.indexes i
INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON i.object_id = t.object_id AND 

t.type = 'U'
LEFT JOIN sys.extended_properties AS EP ON EP.major_id = T.[object_id]
where is_primary_key=1
```

2.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT'
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type_desc IN ('PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT')
```

3.

```
 SELECT Count(*)
    FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
    WHERE  CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE  CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
```

I think this is the better way to do that

Comment: No, it is not the best for SQL-Server. Using system views is far better. Read Aaron Bertrand's blog: **[The case against INFORMATION_SCHEMA views](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views)**

Answer (score 0):

Third query is correct as it is. But the second query needs to be modified to add checks to exclude SYS Tables.  sys.Objects has System Tables (so we need to add a check) whereas Information Schema doesnot includes System Tables

2)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT'
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type_desc IN ('PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT') AND is_ms_shipped <>1
```

3)

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE  CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this too may help you.

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) [Ct_PK]
FROM    SYS.OBJECTS 
WHERE   TYPE = 'PK'
```